# SMTP-Relay-Server as a Service - Deliverability Services like Mandrill

Tags: email, email-relay

**Situation**

There are a bunch of different email delivery services available. A lot of them offer SMTP interfaces and email relaying:

- [Amazon Simple Email Service (SES)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp.html)
- [Mailchimp Mandrill](https://mandrillapp.com/)
- [Sendgrid](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/smtp_ports.html)
- [Postmark](https://postmarkapp.com)
- [SocketLabs](http://www.socketlabs.com)
- [mailjet](https://www.mailjet.com/support/how-can-i-configure-my-smtp-parameters,2.htm)
- [ElasticEmail](http://elasticemail.com)
- [SMTP2GO](http://www.smtp2go.com)
- and many more

**Question**

Which email relaying service can be used as a salesforce email relay?

**Known Integrations**

- [SMTP2Go: Salesforce SMTP Setup](http://www.smtp2go.com/docs/salesforce/)

Comment: Hi Christian, are you looking for off the shelf AppExchange integration, or something that you and your devs would integrate yourself? Googling many of these with "salesforce" included in the search terms shows that there are API libraries if not actual integrations.

Comment: Hi Christian, in order to use as much vanilla functionality as possible it is required to use the standard Salesforce SMTP-Relay. The SMTP-Relay has to be used in order to make sure that workflow email alerts and process builder emails are working as expected. (And I already searched for SMTP Relay this post is one of the to 5 hits https://www.google.ch/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=smtp-relay-server+salesforce )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of research I found the following potential solutions:

1. Office 365
2. Google Apps
3. SMTP2Go

It is possible for all 3 services to allow users to access their SMTP servers without username and password but require IP restrictions. This is the criteria which is required by salesforce.

Office 365 and Google Apps are not capable of sending "mass" mails. They should be used for small amounts of data and mails. SMTP2Go isn't as restrictive as Microsoft and Google but they want to be payed per mail.

Based on this research we can conclude that there are services available but "api only" service like most of the list above should be considered during implementation as well. In case you want to stick to a vanilla solution SMTP2Go seems to be the way to go.